# Copy text to clipboard, Linux, make it permanent

Tags: linux, lazarus

I use Lazarus 1.7. Ubuntu 14. I copy text to clipboard,

`Clipboard.AsText:='some txt';`

When my app exits, clipboard cleared by OS: how to copy text permanent? So after exit of app, the clipboard still has this text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, since [X has no "clipboard" per se](https://tronche.com/gui/x/icccm/sec-2.html#s-2). A process must remain open to respond to the `SelectionRequest` event that actually requests the contents of the clipboard.

Comment: [Copy-to-clipboard, text clears after exiting my app](https://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php?topic=36112.0) or [How to fix empty GTK2 clipboard on exit](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Clipboard#How_to_fix_empty_GTK2_clipboard_on_exit) or [Persistent Clipboard](http://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php/topic,35244)